# How to handle browser window or tab using Behat and Mink PHP

Tags: php, browser, automation, behat, mink

I have test that click on link and then new browser window open and in new browser window I need to check some elements are present. How to switch to new Browser window that was opened using BEHAT/MINK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `switchToWindow($windowName)` method.

```
$this->getSession()->switchToWindow($windowName);
```

Method declaration is [here](https://github.com/Behat/Mink/blob/master/src/Behat/Mink/Session.php#L281)

You can get all windows from current session and then switch to the second one for example

```
$windowNames = $this->getSession()->getWindowNames();
if(count($windowNames) > 1) {
    $this->getSession()->switchToWindow($windowNames[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, I know about this method but I don't know how to get window name

Comment: if your window name is a dynamic for example, then just use getWindowNames() as I mentioned above and switch to the second name. Maybe you need also to add method for waiting while second window will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone, the window names are an array.  So, using Igor's answer, $windowNames[1] is the 2nd tab, [2] would be a 3rd, and so fourth.  If you are wondering how to go back to the first tab after this, simply remove the 'if' block (or check if at least 1 window exists) from Igor's answer and make a new function like so:

```
  /**
  * @Given I go to the first tab
  */
  public function goToFirstTab()
  {
    $windowNames = $this->getSession()->getWindowNames();
    $this->getSession()->switchToWindow($windowNames[0]);
  }
```